# how to simplify the result of hiding variable using z3?

Tags: z3, smt

I wish to hide some variables and get the simplified results.

I wish to hide `c1`, `c2` and `d` as follows:

```
(declare-const v1 Real)
(declare-const v2 Real)
(elim-quantifiers (exists ((c1 Real) (c2 Real)(d Real)) 
                          (and (<= c1 10.0) (>= c2 5.0) (>= d 0.0) 
                               (= v1 (+ c1 d)) 
                               (= v2 (+ c2 d)))))
```

However the result seems complex, in fact, the result should be `v2>=5.0 & v1<= v2+5.0`, I used to use `(apply ctx-solver-simplify)` the code is

```
(declare-const v1 Real)
(declare-const v2 Real)
(assert (elim-quantifiers (exists ((c1 Real) (c2 Real)(d Real)) 
                                  (and (<= c1 10.0) (>= c2 5.0) (>= d 0.0)
                                       (= v1 (+ c1 d)) 
                                       (= v2 (+ c2 d))))))
(apply ctx-solver-simplify)
```

However, when I add apply ....There is and error,the script can not work. could someone help me to fix it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not an error, but the result just happens to be in a form that is not to your liking, am I correct?

Comment: I mean, the when I run the code, there is an error. Not the result is wrong

Comment: Oh yes, the query is malformed; pad's answer below shows how to apply quantifier elimination combined with subsequent simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [then](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/strategies#h21) tactic to apply quantifier elimination to the formula and apply context simplification to all sub-goals produced:

```
(declare-const v1 Real)
(declare-const v2 Real)
(assert (exists ((c1 Real) (c2 Real)(d Real)) 
                                  (and (<= c1 10.0) (>= c2 5.0) (>= d 0.0)
                                       (= v1 (+ c1 d)) 
                                       (= v2 (+ c2 d)))))
(apply (then qe ctx-solver-simplify))
```

The result is `v2 >= 5.0 and v1 - v2 <= 5.0` which is quite close to what you want.

Comment: `qe` is the tactic for quantifier elimination; it is corresponding to `elim-quantifiers`.